# What is the use to define :class as an array and not as an object in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm reading the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html) about :class and it seems that everything that is done with an array, can be done with an object. I think that in JS an array is actually and object, so I'm not understanding the difference as to give it a special mention in the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array` is a *type* of `Object` that lends itself better to some uses. For example, you can run functions like `map` and `filter` on arrays much easier (instead of converting an object to a set of keys or values). In some cases, you may be using such functions to compose a set of classes to assign, and in other cases, you may have a class name you might want to assign based on the object value. Luckily Vue allows both.

Comment: So it is for practical reasons that arrays conveniently provide. Thanks!